# Какая часть речи "вообще" в моей фразе?

Tags: части-речи

> *Кто-нибудь мне ответит вообще?*

Среди значений слова на [Грамоте](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5) я не нашёл подходящего смысла.

Я правильно понимаю, что это не вводное слово и запятая не нужна?

Comment: Не нужна. Значение 1. в Грамоте: в общем и целом.

Comment: И правда! Спасибо, Галина! Как я сразу не догадался! Стоящий вопрос или лучше удалить на фиг?

Comment: Та хай висить - исть не просить...

Comment: *Та хай висить - исть не просить...* =))) Тогда прошу Вас (так же как и Вы других) ответ, как полагается, дать. ;)

Comment: Тёмыч, спасибо. Шаронушка придёт - всё красиво распишет. Я щас вопрос сочиняю про как мы все тут делали книгу: https://ridero.ru/books/obryvki_iz_realnostei_potegurim/

Comment: Понятно, удачи!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**О наречие *вообще***

Вопрос об обособлении слова ***вообще*** никогда не бывает лишним. Эта тема не раз обсуждалась на форуме, причем часто мнения отвечающих не совпадают, да и ответы звучат как-то неуверенно.

1) Эту задачу действительно **сложно решить с помощью перечня значений,** которые даются в словаре или справочнике.

Семантика слова ***вообще*** связана с идеей  противопоставления **общее/целое/основное — частное/конкретное/исключительное.**  В каждом  случае это может обозначено как *в общем, в целом, в основном, а также обычно, всегда, как правило*. **Запоминать всё это не имеет смысла.**

2) Наречие ***вообще*** встречается чаще, поэтому основное внимание нужно уделить вводному слову ***вообще***.

3) Вводное слово ***вообще*** имеет значение ***вообще говоря,*** но существуют парные варианты, когда наречие сложно отличить от вводного слова. Поэтому надо дополнительно проверить **возможность его обособления.** Это и есть два признака для вводного слова.

**Решение задачи:** ***Кто-нибудь мне отвЕтит вообще?***

1) Это не вводное слово, так как нет значения "вообще говоря."

2) В предложении присутствует **инверсия**, ожидаемый порядок слов такой: *Кто-нибудь мне  **вообще** ответит? Или: Кто-нибудь мне  **вообще-то** ответит?*

3)  Автор реплики высказывает **нетерпение** (а это значение **междометия**). Его уже интересует не конкретные ответы, а сам факт: **будут ли ответы или нет?** Так проявляется семантика наречия ***вообще*** (в целом, в общем).

4) Интонация  ***вообще*** тоже особая, присоединительная. Ударение падает на глагол, а ***вообще*** произносится в конце фразы, с небольшой  паузой, что напоминает обособление.

**И вывод.** Обособлять наречие ***вообще*** не следует, но в нем при инверсии в значительной  степени присутствует **дополнительное значение междометия.**

Comment: Спасибо, Sharon! Любопытно всё это!)

Comment: Я правильно понял, что у меня это часть речи, сочетающая в себе одновременно функции и наречия, и междометия?

Comment: В принципе, да. Слово "вообще" может быть междометием, но обычно как реплика-предложение: "Ну и дела у вас тут творятся! Вообще!" Это информация из "Справочника".  А здесь такой интересный случай, когда это формально наречие, но оно содержит дополнительную эмоциональную коннотацию.

Answer (score 2):

Значение слова в этой фразе можно определить так: *"хоть кто-нибудь (из вас), хоть что-нибудь, хоть как-то"*. Похоже, что слово функционирует здесь как побудительная **частица** или междометие.

Comment: Спасибо, Александр! Очень интересно!

Answer (score 1):

В идеографическом словаре:
[вообще](https://file:///C:/Users/lenovo/AppData/Local/Packages/Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe/TempState/Downloads/Voobsche-3954%20(1).html) — в отношении всего; в общем и целом; в целом (в едином целом).

В словаре Ефремовой:
**вообще**, *наречие*
1. а) во всех отношениях, по отношению ко всему, в целом;
б) в общем, в основном (не входя в подробности, не касаясь частностей);
в) абстрактно, отвлеченно.

"Вообще" в этом предложении является наречием — запятая, соответственно, не требуется.
Точный смысл слова зависит, мне кажется, от предыдущего текста.

Comment: Спасибо, Римма! "Вообще" я имел в виду как слово, которое делает вопрос более вызывающим, произнесённым если не с негодованием, то хотя бы с лёгким нетерпением, лёгкой обидой на то, что не отвечают. При этом всё перечисленное, это напряжение может присутствовать, а может и нет. То есть реагировать на это соответственно, отвечать резко ещё нет оснований, по крайней мере при переписке. При живом общении, конечно же, всё скажет тон, интонация, и тогда разговор может пройти и на повышенных тонах, и на спокойных.